# Login to Yahoo with mechanize and python

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to login into a yahoo page, and i feel like the following setup should work, it worked for gmail but not here.  On submit it just pulls up the same page again

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()

cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

#br.set_debug_http(True)
#br.set_debug_redirects(True)
#br.set_debug_responses(True)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

r = br.open('https://login.yahoo.com/config/login;_ylt=AwrGB7pqzTxUF9oAigC3cJ8u?.src=fantasy&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/')

br.select_form(nr=0)

br.form['login'] = 'login'
br.form['passwd'] = 'passwd'

br.submit()
```

Comment: your code works fine, are you sure you are passing correct values of username and password?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing actual credentials:

```
br.form['login'] = 'login'
br.form['passwd'] = 'passwd'
```

If you have stored login and password in a variable, you should do like:

```
br.form['login'] = login
br.form['passwd'] = passwd
```

Comment: I did not not put actual credential here, but in my code i replaced 'login' with 'mylogin' and 'passwd' with 'mypasswd'

Answer (score 0):

```
br.form['username'] = yourusername
response = br.submit()
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['passwd'] = yourpassword
response = br.submit()
```

I had success with this. Yahoo has you first input your username and then submit to access the password.